# ASP.Net Chart namespace error

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am using VS2012 in .Net 4.5 and i added an existing vb class which are all styling functions for the ASP.Net chart control. The Import statement for
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting is red squiggly, its not being recognized. I have a reference to system.web in the website. I cannot find anywhere in the add reference area an object called System.Web.UI, I do see a System.Web.DataVisualization did it change? I googled around and dont see anywhere where it notes a change in that namespace. The intellisense from System.Web.UI. doesnt even contain an option for DataVisualization anymore

Edit: I created a whole new website from scratch, my toolbox is empty and using right click "Choose Items" i cant even add any to my toolbox, this is the issue, it sees no Chart control or any other control for that matter

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference on `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll`

Comment: please see my edit, any reason why a new website comes up with an empty toolbox? is my install of vs2012 corrupted in some way?

Comment: That is not the dll for the asp.net chart control. And the wierd thing is my .aspx page with the chart can reference it and the class i added to write the chart styling functions which is in the app_code folder, cannot. I've had chartstyling classes in almost all my projects and never had this problem.